# FaultServer is rpping serverfault

Tags: discussion

[FaultServer](http://www.faultserver.com/) is ripping serverfault. Even it's name is also a copy of serverfault name. For example, [FaultServer Question](http://www.faultserver.com/q/answers-why-is-hash-join-slow-in-postgresql-9-1-502198.html) ripped [Why is hash join slow in postgresql 9.1?](https://serverfault.com/questions/502198/why-is-hash-join-slow-in-postgresql-9-1). Is there anything can be done

Comment: note: the procedure for reporting scrapers has changed - see [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers) for more info, however, the tl;dr is: Send all reports of SCRAPERs to team@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: This is not the first time for FaultServer. [There is clearly only one solution.](http://i.imgur.com/0JDPrTP.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Please send this as an e-mail to `team@stackexchange.com`